# Inserir Items do combobox usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core

Tenho uma aplicação WindowsForms e nela estou tentando inserir items de um combobox e salvar no banco de dados usando Entity Framework Core. O maior problema é que insere apenas um item do combobox, mesmo fazendo um laço para percorrer as informações do combobox.

```
private void InserirDados()
        {
            ExemploDbContext context = new ExemploDbContext();
            Sala sala = new Sala();
            Aluno aluno = new Aluno();

            sala.NomeSala = textBox1.Text;

            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                sala.SalaAlunos = new List<SalaAluno>();
                sala.SalaAlunos.Add(new SalaAluno { AlunoId = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]) });
            }

            context.Add(sala);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Abaixo as entidades criadas

```
public class Sala
    {
        public int SalaId { get; set; }
        public string NomeSala { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SalaAluno> SalaAlunos { get; set; }
    }

public class Aluno
    {
        public int AlunoId { get; set; }
        public string NomeAluno { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SalaAluno> SalaAlunos { get; set; }
    }

public class SalaAluno
    {
        public int SalaAlunoId { get; set; }

        public int AlunoId { get; set; }
        public int SalaId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você está inicializando a lista a cada iteração do loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
            sala.SalaAlunos = new List<SalaAluno>(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            sala.SalaAlunos.Add(new SalaAluno { AlunoId = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]) });
    }
```

inicie a lista antes do for.

E você também pode utilizar async para não congelar a tela durante o processo,
e utilize o using para o contexto ser descartado quando não for mais necessário.

```
private async void InserirDados()
{
    using (ExemploDbContext context = new ExemploDbContext())
    {
        Sala sala = new Sala();
        sala.NomeSala = textBox1.Text;
        sala.SalaAlunos = new List<SalaAluno>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            sala.SalaAlunos.Add(new SalaAluno { AlunoId = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]) });
        }

        await context.AddAsync(sala);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não tinha reparado esse detalhe, muito obrigado!